# PHP Else, Elseif Logic Correct?

Tags: php

I am trying to have 3 actions based on an order being 0 percent fulfilled, 100 percent fulfilled or somewhere in the middle.

The tests I have ran so far suggest this is correct but as I could check every possibility I was hoping someone could run their eyes over it and point out any obvious wrong-doings.

```
//$success & $unsuccess are counts of the good/bad fulfilment items.

$percentfulfilled = round((($success/($success+$unsuccess))*100),2);

//If 0% fulfillled
if($percentfulfilled == '0')
{

}
//If 1-99% fulfilled
elseif($percentfulfilled < '100' && $percentfulfilled > '0')
{

}
//If 100% fulfilled
elseif($percentfulfilled = 100)
{

}
```

Comment: $percentfulfilled == 100 (check this)

Comment: Last statement, `=` is an assignment operator, you want the comparison operator `==`

Comment: I'd only perform two if statements, if it equals 0 one thing and if it equals 100 do another thing, if it equals none of them do the in between thing. Also remember to fix your comparison operator as you're currently assigning `$precentfulfilled` to 100.

Comment: why are you doing arithmetic operations on strings? :S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your last statement is missing an equal

```
elseif($percentfulfilled == 100)
                        //^here
```

In the last stament you were not checking the condition but you were assigning a value to variable.

Comment: Thanks for this! This was an error on my part! I was checking more on the logic but your answer also was very helpful :)